# SQL (Bigquery) - Populate multiple columns in existing rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

EDIT: As @Prateek suggested, I changed my working flow - Now the first query is used as ***"Structure-Query"*** that I run every time that I want to clear and recreate my table with the desired variables structure. The second query became my ***"Population-Query"***, where I fill my empty structured table. The meaning is that now I have a bunch of sub-tables that my population-query joins and push at once.

Given this structured table with no rows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE primary_table (
        EVENT_ID int64,
        TREATMENT_TIME timestamp,
        AGE int64,
        HEIGHT int64,
        WEIGHT int64,
        SEX string, 
        ICU_ADMIT timestamp,
        ICU_DISCH timestamp,
        ICUSTAYS_COUNT int64,
);
```

And after the initial population with the total wanted rows at the end of the day:

```
INSERT INTO primary_Table (
        EVENT_ID,
        TREATMENT_TIME
    )
   SELECT 
        event_id,
        cast(treatment_time as timestamp)
   FROM some_table_1
```

I have this half filled `primary_table`:

| EVENT_ID | TREATMENT_TIME | AGE | HEIGHT | WEIGHT | SEX | ICU_ADMIT | ICU_DISCH | ICUSTAYS_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32342 | 2156-03-30 06:41:00 UTC |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 32342 | 2156-03-30 06:41:00 UTC |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 45084 | 2165-03-29 10:23:00 UTC |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 45084 | 2165-03-29 10:23:00 UTC |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

I want to start and populate more columns in the existing rows.
The rows should be update on  `primary_table.EVENT_ID = some_table_2.EVENT_ID`.

For example, this table as `some_table_2`:

| EVENT_ID | HEIGHT | WEIGHT | SEX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32342 | 45 | 66.7 | F |
| 32342 | 70 | 102 | M |
| 45084 | 40 | 80.3 | M |
| 45084 | 89 | 70.2 | M |

Should be added to the `primary_table` like this:

| EVENT_ID | TREATMENT_TIME | AGE | HEIGHT | WEIGHT | SEX | ICU_ADMIT | ICU_DISCH | ICUSTAYS_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32342 | 2156-03-30 06:41:00 UTC |  | 45 | 66.7 | F |  |  |  |
| 32342 | 2156-03-30 06:41:00 UTC |  | 70 | 102 | M |  |  |  |
| 45084 | 2165-03-29 10:23:00 UTC |  | 40 | 80.3 | M |  |  |  |
| 45084 | 2165-03-29 10:23:00 UTC |  | 89 | 70.2 | M |  |  |  |

- I want to keep the structure of the primary table as I created it and I don't want to add new rows.
- I need to update multiple columns each time.
- I can't update all the columns in one query (Bigquery quota issues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple rows can be inserted, but updating existing rows would be difficult in a single shot. As for updating specific values to each row, you need to add a unique **WHERE** clause.

A smarter solution would be to write a small piece of code, that would read the data from the source (file/network, etc) and perform a bulk update on the **primary_table**

Or if you are trying to copy from another table, write a Stored Function to read data from another table and based on **EVENT_ID**, construct a query to update **primary_table**

Answer (score 1):

What about dropping and re-creating the table and using a join to add the new columns:

```
create or replace table DW_pmo.primary_table as 
select pt.EVENT_ID, pt.TREATMENT_TIME, t2.AGE, t2.HEIGHT, t2.WEIGHT,
   pt.SEX, pt.ICU_ADMIT, pt.ICU_DISCH, pt.ICUSTAYS_COUNT 
from DW_pmo.primary_table pt
   inner join DW_pmo.some_table_2 t2 
      on pt.EVENT_ID = t2.EVENT_ID
```

Comment: I didn't want to recreate the table again and again. The predeterminate structure is used to keep me from creating wrong column types .